# Peut-on porter les cheveux « en touffe » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, coiffure

Est-ce qu’il y a un mot spécifique pour ce style de cheveux ?

[image: cheveux]

Mon dictionnaire néerlandais–français parle d’*une touffe de cheveux*. Néanmoins, les résultats que Google Images donne pour ce terme ne correspondent pas à l’idée que j’avais en tête.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Une touffe de cheveux indique plutôt des cheveux dont on ne prend pas vraiment soin.

Les images google présentées sont des photos de chignons.

Answer (score 4):

Ce genre de coupe de cheveux s'appelle de façon générale un [chignon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chignon). Les résultats sur un moteur de recherche seront surement beaucoup plus proches de ce que tu cherches.

Answer (score 1):

A titre informatif, dans le même champ lexical il y a : natte, tresse, queue-de-cheval, couette.